# How to swipe-to-delete in a TableView with custom Table View cells?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swipe-gesture

Currently, I have a screen that shows a TableView with custom cells that each have one text field and one button. I am storing the text field's data inputs into **taskName dict** and the button's title selection (from a pop-up screen) into **taskTime dict**.

However, my issue is when I swipe-to-delete a row in the TableView, it deletes the data stored in the row, but doesn't delete the row itself (as seen in the animation below).

Here is my code:

**Screen with TableView + custom cells**

```
class TaskListViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var taskList: SelfSizedTableView!
    
    var taskCount: Int = 1
    var taskName = [Int:String]()
    var taskTime = [Int:String]()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // Set initial taskTime value
        taskTime[0] = "Set time"

        taskList.delegate = self
        taskList.dataSource = self
    }
}

extension TaskListViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                   numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return taskCount
    }
    
    // Return custom cell + data to insert in table view
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                   cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "taskCell", for: indexPath) as! TaskCell
        
        cell.delegate = self
        
        // Configure nameField and timeButton in taskCell
        cell.nameField.text = taskName[indexPath.row]
        cell.timeButton.setTitle(taskTime[indexPath.row], for: .normal)
        
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                   commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle,
                   forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        // Update # of rows in taskList
        taskCount -= 1

        // Row that is deleted
        let deleteRowIndex = indexPath.row
        print(deleteRowIndex)

        // Remove taskName + taskTime from dictionary
        taskName[deleteRowIndex] = nil
        taskTime[deleteRowIndex] = nil

        // Delete row from table view
        let indexPaths = [indexPath]
        taskList.deleteRows(at: indexPaths, with: .fade)
        
        // Reload table view with new data
        taskList.reloadData()
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all don't use **two dictionaries** as data source use **one array** of a custom struct

```
struct Task {
    var name, time : String
}
```

---

```
var tasks = [Task]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    // Set initial taskTime value
    tasks.append(Task(name:"", time: "Set time"))

    taskList.delegate = self
    taskList.dataSource = self
}
```

And don't hard-code the number of cells, `count` the array, `taskCount` is not needed.

```
extension TaskListViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                   numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tasks.count
    }
    
    // Return custom cell + data to insert in table view
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                   cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "taskCell", for: indexPath) as! TaskCell
        
        cell.delegate = self
        
        // Configure nameField and timeButton in taskCell
        let task = tasks(indexPath.row)
        cell.nameField.text = task.name
        cell.timeButton.setTitle(task.time, for: .normal)
        
        return cell
    }
```

And it's highly recommended to use `tableView(_:trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt:` rather than `tableView(_:commit:forRowAt`

In this method remove the item at the given index path and call `deleteRows(at:with:)`. Calling `reloadData()` right after `deleteRows(at:with:)` is redundant. The latter methods updates the UI

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
        
        let delete = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { [unowned self] action, view, completionHandler in
            self.tasks.remove(at: indexPath.row) 
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
            completionHandler(true)
        }
        return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [delete])
    }
}
```

Of course you have to refactor the other occurrences of the two data source dictionaries to match the data source array.

Comment: Thank you, I was running into blockers using the two dictionaries as my data source, so I appreciate the guidance in refactoring my data more efficiently and the recommendation for implementing the swipe-to-delete action. This worked great!

Answer (score 1):

You must be remove the element from your dataSource array in your `commit editingStyle` method before reload tableView. After changes your method will look like below:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
               commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle,
               forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    taskName.remove(at: indexPath.row) // remove element from array
    taskTime.remove(at: indexPath.row) // remove element from array

    // Delete row from table view
    taskList.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    
    // Reload table view with new data
    taskList.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: In my case, taskName and taskTime are dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
               commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle,
               forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    // Remove taskName + taskTime from dictionary
    taskName.remove(at: indexPath.row) // remove element from array
    taskTime.remove(at: indexPath.row)

    // Delete row from table view
    taskList.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    
    // Reload table view with new data
    taskList.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: In my case, taskName and taskTime are dictionaries.